# "The Annotated Turing" on listing all binary numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: sets, mathematical-foundations, books

[image: Page 31]
In his book "The Annotated Turing" in the first sentence on page 32 Charles Petzold wrote:

> These are binary numbers between 0 and 1, and (judging from the way we
> created these numbers) all the binary numbers between 0 and 1, and
> hence all the real numbers between 0 and 1.

And then at the bottom of the page there is a note:

> It may also seem as if we've stumbled on a method to enumerate all the
> real numbers between 0 and 1...

Followed by a brief explanation of why we really have not.

These two sentences contradict each other. The first one says we've made a list of all real numbers and the bottom note says we have not. So I have to questions regarding this:

1. Is it a mistake or am I getting something wrong?
2. If we have not listed all the real numbers between 0 and 1, then what have we listed?

Comment: Without knowing the full context of the proof, we can only guess at the logic and structure of the proof that you're quoting excerpts from.  That seems like it might make it hard to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for response! I've added a screenshot with full text that goes right before the mentioned sentence

Comment: That still isn't the full proof, and it seems like we're still forced to guess at what is happening here, but I'd bet pretty confidently that my answer is correct.

Comment: I struggled with the author’s choice of words here as well. He does indeed seem to say that the method he outlines will enumerate all the binary numbers between 0 and 1. This obviously cannot be true (as he points out in the footnote, the list does not contain any transcendental numbers). But then he just continues assuming that the list he has created can be put into a one-to-one correspondence with the real numbers, and thus the power set has the same cardinality as the continuum. I don’t doubt the conclusion but how he arrives there makes no sense to me either.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the full proof, but it most likely has the form "Assume that the set is countable.  Consider any enumeration.  Then (blah-blah-blah) shows that there is a number not in the enumeration.  That's a contradiction, so our assumption must have been wrong."

If that's the structure of the proof, then pointing out that the proof appears to say two contradictory things is not a surprise; that's entirely the point of the line of reasoning, to show that if you start with a particular assumption, you reach absurd results.

What's actually true?  The truth: that list doesn't actually contain all the real numbers.  Assuming that it does is a faulty assumption.

It's possible that the text could have been written a little more carefully to caveat that the statement about it containing all numbers; but oh well, no one's perfect.  Books written for a popular audience, in particular, aren't always the best source if you want a precise and careful proof of a mathematical theorem.

Comment: Thanks for response! I've added a screenshot with full text that goes right before the mentioned sentence

Comment: What I posted is not a proof of any kind. The author just enumerates all subsets of natural numbers, that's all. And then tells that it's the same as enumerating all real numbers (or it isn't, that's not clear and hence the question)

Comment: @AntonJebrak, well, I'm saying that the answer to your question is that this list does not enumerate all real numbers, so I think I've answered your question about which claim is true.

Comment: @D.W. I think we can all agree it does not enumerate all the real numbers. The question then is, how can there be a one-to-one correspondence between the real numbers and the power set of the natural numbers, if there is a one-to-one correspondence between the power set of the natural numbers and the list enumerated by the author?

Comment: @AlexanderHøst, that's a new question, and should be asked separately.  Comment threads are intended to help improve the answer, rather than to pose and answer follow-up questions.  The answer is that the premise of your "if" is false; there is not a one-to-one correspondence between the power set of the natural numbers and the list enumerated by the author.

Comment: It’s the same question asked in a different way. In my estimation you have just misunderstood the question (and I don’t blame you, it’s a bit unclear). I, however, own the book and have read the passage in context. My comment reflects what I think is being asked.

Comment: @AlexanderHøst, ok, great!  Sounds like you have an idea what you think might be being asked - that sounds like useful.  Perhaps you could write your own answer, or ask a new question that more clearly articulates the question!